# Java: How do I print an array from another class? My array contains another variable from that class

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, methods

Okay so this is my code i know its messy and full of other errors, i I am still trying to learn. I know i could do it in one class but that takes away from the OOP portion of java. I figure if I am going to learn i may as well learn right.

I have been trying to figure out how to print out that `charHpArray` for two days and everything i found on google has been useless because they dont contain another array . Essentially I am trying to make it so level works as the parameter, so when `level` = 1 `hp` is 5, and when `level` is 2 `hp` is 10 and so on.

Also if you could tell me why `level + #` isnt working that would be great. 
//if you want to take a crack at that too, I am trying to make `mage`, `arch`, and `war`, all have different starting bonuses so `war` would have a little more health than the basic `level` bonus.

** ALL ANSWERS ARE ENCOURAGED, EVEN IF IT MEANS NEW IDEAS IM JUST TRYING TO LEARN**

Thanks.

The Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random roll = new Random();

        System.out.println("Welcome To Adventure Heroes");
        System.out.println("-------------------");

        System.out.println("You awake to the sound of screaming, \"GET AWAY FROM ME!\"");
        System.out.println("You call out to the voice in the distance...");
        System.out.println("There is no answer");
        System.out.println("You run towards the troubled screams in the distance");
        System.out.println("You see a man on the floor being kicked, without hesitation you charge in and push the attacker off the man.");
        System.out.println("You examine the man to see if he is okay. When you look up the attacker is gone.");
        System.out.println("\"Thank you so much... erm, come to think of it I've never seen you around these parts. What is Your name?\"");

        String yourName = input.next();

        System.out.println("\"What a weird name, Hi " + yourName + ", I'm Borgan\"");
        System.out.print("\"Well "  + yourName + ", your journey begins here.\"");

        Character.getcharHp() ;


        public class Character {

            int[] level ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
            int[] charHpArray = {5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50};

            Character(int[]  charHp)
            {
                charHp = charHpArray;
            }

            public int[] getCharHp() {
                return charHpArray; 
            } 

            int xp;
            int def;
            int meleeDmg;
            int magicDmg;

            function increment(array)

                int mage[] = {
                charHpArray[level],
                def = level + 2,
                meleeDmg = level + 1,
                magicDmg = level + 6
            };

            int archer[] = {charHp[level] = level + 4,
            def = level + 3,
            meleeDmg= level + 4,
            magicDmg = level + 1};

        int[] warrior = {getcharHp()[level] = level + 5,
        def = level + 4,
        meleeDmg = level + 3,
        magicDmg = level + 0};

        int player[][] = {mage, archer, warrior};
}
```

Comment: Dylan, Please correct the syntax errors on your string out's and other syntax errors you have and post a error list for your compile if you get one.

Comment: Also you have to remember all array index's start with 0

Comment: `function increment(array) ... `: What is this code about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this answers any of your questions - but here is some info about using arrays in Java.

> I have been trying to figure out how to print out that `charHpArray`
>   for two days and everything i found on google has been useless because
>   they dont contain another array . Essentially I am trying to make it
>   so `level` works as the parameter, so when `level` = 1 `hp` is 5, and
>   when `level` is 2 `hp` is 10 and so on.

*Printing charHpArray using level:*

The case where the array `charHpArray` elements are printed using `level` arrays elements as the index -  as follows.

```
int[] level ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] charHpArray = {5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50};

for (int i : level) {
    int j = charHpArray [i];
    System.out.println("Level " + i + ", charHpArray element: " + j);
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
Level 1, charHpArray element: 10
Level 2, charHpArray element: 15
Level 3, charHpArray element: 20
Level 4, charHpArray element: 25
Level 5, charHpArray element: 30
Level 6, charHpArray element: 35
Level 7, charHpArray element: 40
Level 8, charHpArray element: 45
Level 9, charHpArray element: 50
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at Testing.main(Testing.java:35)
```

Note that the `charHpArray`'s first element 5 is *not* printed. Note the last line in the output: its a runtime exception; see the explanation below.

> Also if you could tell me why level + # isnt working that would be
>   great.

In Java, arrays have elements and indexes. The first element in the array is of index 0 (always). The next element has the index 1, and so on. So the last element of the array has an index of: array length *minus* 1.

Here is Oracle's Java tutorials for using [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

So, if you try to access an element in an index that is not there in an array, you will encounter a runtime exception: [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

`charHpArray` has 10 elements. Each element can be accessed and printed using its index as follows:

```
System.out.println("First element charHpArray [0]: " + charHpArray[0]); // this will print 5
System.out.println("Second element charHpArray [1]: " + charHpArray[1]); // this will print 10
...
System.out.println("Tenth element charHpArray [9]: " + charHpArray[9]); // this will print 50
```

*-OR-*

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Element " + (i+1) + " of charHpArray: " + charHpArray[i]);
}
```

The output:

```
Element 1 of charHpArray: 5
Element 2 of charHpArray: 10
Element 3 of charHpArray: 15
Element 4 of charHpArray: 20
Element 5 of charHpArray: 25
Element 6 of charHpArray: 30
Element 7 of charHpArray: 35
Element 8 of charHpArray: 40
Element 9 of charHpArray: 45
Element 10 of charHpArray: 50
```

In the above code 10 is the length of the array (array has 10 elements). This can be arrived at within the code using the length variable of an array: `charHpArray.length`

```
System.out.println("Size of the array: " + charHpArray.length); // this prints 10.
```

So, the code to print can be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < charHpArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Element " + (i+1) + " of charHpArray: " + charHpArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I did try your first suggestion however I am now getting the semi-colon expected error.

Comment: Can you post the code, so that I can see what is the issue.  May be you are missing the semi-colon somewhere in the code?

Comment: All the code snippets I have posted compile and run fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a level array but you don't indicate the level int value. This is why the add is not working (because level is an array and you're adding an int to it). I would suggest trying to make use of a HashMap to map level to hp (e.g. call this field levelHpMap, and make it constant) and then having a separate field that each character has set, called level, that is used to initialize the characters attributes/fields (instead of hp).

The additional characters would extend the Character class through inheritance.